# Better way to kill a Form after the FormClosing event is overridden to hide rather than close?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I have a simple Windows Form that hosts property controls at runtime. When the user clicks Close [X] I want to keep the window and its contents alive rather than killing it by handling the FormClosing event, canceling the event and simply hiding the form.

That's fine but at close of the application I need to actually close the window. I implemented the below but it feels kludgey. *Is there a simpler, more clever way to handle this situation?* (The form's controller calls KillForm explicitly after it receives a closing event from the main window.)

```
Friend Class HostForm
    Private _hideInsteadOfClosing As Boolean = True

    Private Sub HostForm_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) _
    Handles Me.FormClosing
        If _hideInsteadOfClosing Then
            Me.Hide()
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub KillForm()
        _hideInsteadOfClosing = False
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Good question, a problem I encounter too. If you have something like Messenger, which when you press the X, minimises instead of exits, when you try to shut down your computer for example, Windows effectively presses the X of your application itself to close it gracefully, which causes it to minimise rather than exit. I haven't been able to figure out a way to distinguish user clicking X and Windows doing the same, and would love to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can examine the value of the [`CloseReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property of the event args object. If it is `UserClosing`, hide the form, otherwise close it. For all possible values of this property, check the [CloseReason enumeration documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).